# Como obtener que códigos fueron ignorados para insertar en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Parece compleja la pregunta al menos para mi llevo dando vueltas al asunto pensando si existe alguna single query donde pueda insertar múltiples datos que no existan y los que ya existen ignorarlos pero a la ves obtener cuales códigos fueron ignorados en la inserción.

Con INSERT IGNORE se ejecuta perfecta la query inserto los datos que no existe y los que están duplicados los ignora pero sin el resultado de cuales códigos fueron ignorados.

Comment: `SHOW WARNINGS;` ?

Comment: Creo que la mejor solución para este caso sería tener una función que verifique si el dato existe antes de insertarlo, si existe, guardas el código en un array y devuelves `false` para que la inserción no se haga. Si no existe haces la inserción. Al final de todo verificas el array para saber qué códigos no se insertaron.